# Get location results from another class in swift

Tags: ios, swift, geolocation, mapkit, cllocationmanager

How to get location results from one class (GPSLocation) from (userLocation.swift) and use them in another class in file (target.swift)..?

I need countryCode, city, longitude and latitude from:

**userLocation.swift**

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class GPSLocation {

func getGPSLocation(completion: () -> Void) {

    let locManager = CLLocationManager()
    var currentLocation: CLLocation!
    locManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

    if (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedWhenInUse || CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedAlways) {

        currentLocation = locManager.location

        let latitude = String(format: "%.7f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)
        let longitude = String(format: "%.7f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)
        let location = CLLocation(latitude: currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)

        fetchCountryAndCity(location: location) { countryCode, city in
            // debugPrint("Country:", countryCode)
            // debugPrint("City:", city)
        }
        // debugPrint("Latitude:", latitude)
        // debugPrint("Longitude:", longitude)
    }
}

//MARK: Find countryCode & City name from longitude & latitude

func fetchCountryAndCity(location: CLLocation, completion: @escaping (String, String) -> ()) {
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { placemarks, error in
        if let error = error {
            debugPrint(error)
        } else if let countryCode = placemarks?.first?.isoCountryCode,
            let city = placemarks?.first?.locality {
            completion(countryCode, city)
        }
    }
}
}
```

And print them in file:

**target.swift**

```
import Foundation

class Post {

 fileprivate func Post() {

    func getLocation() {
        // Get user GPS location (longitude, latitude, Country Code, City)
        let getUserLocation = GPSLocation()
        getUserLocation.getGPSLocation {
            debugPrint("Country:", countryCode)
            debugPrint("City:", city)
            debugPrint("Latitude:", latitude)
            debugPrint("Longitude:", longitude)
        }
    }

  }

}
```

Thank you in advance..!!!

Comment: Create a sharedinstance/singleton?

Comment: When you call `getGPSLocation`, aren't you already printing the stuff you want?

Comment: Pass a closure to `getGPSLocation` and invoke it from the `fetchCountryAndCity` completion handler

Comment: I'm not very good at swift. I was spend two days just to get location results..  :-) But now I need to use them in another file. How to do it..? Looking at share instance thing... is it usual way to do it..? Some code help will be appreciated..

Comment: I think passing the block of code (closure) would be better in your case. just have a look at my code, your can have it as a closure in your class as a variable OR you can pass a completion block to your function by calling it.

Comment: note that you can call the closure (completion) whenever you want in your function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a closure to run after getting location in your `GPSLocation` class. You can achieve it in two way:

You can have a variable of a block code in your `GPSLocation` class like below :

```
typealias completionHanlder = (_ lat: String, _ lng: String) -> Void
var completion: completionHanlder?
```

then in your `Post` class after instantiating `GPSLocation` you can pass a block of codes like :

```
getUserLocation.completion = {
       // do any stuff here     
}
```

**OR** you can pass a block of code to your `getGPSLocation` function. here is how to redefine your function :

```
func getGPSLocation(completion: (_ lat: String, _ lng: String) -> Void) {        
    let locManager = CLLocationManager()
    var currentLocation: CLLocation!
    locManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

    if (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedWhenInUse || CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedAlways) {

    currentLocation = locManager.location

    let latitude = String(format: "%.7f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)
    let longitude = String(format: "%.7f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    let location = CLLocation(latitude: currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)

    fetchCountryAndCity(location: location, completion: { countryCode, city in
        delegate?.fetchedLocationDetails(location: location, countryCode: countryCode, city: city)
    }) { delegate?.failedFetchingLocationDetails(error: $0) }

    debugPrint("Latitude:", latitude)
    debugPrint("Longitude:", longitude)

    completion(latitude, longitude)  // your block of code you passed to this function will run in this way

   }

}
```

and this would be your `Post` class :

```
class Post {

func getLocation() {
    // Get user GPS location (longitude, latitude, Country Code, City)
    let getUserLocation = GPSLocation()
    getUserLocation.getGPSLocation { (lat, lng) in

        debugPrint("Latitude:", lat)
        debugPrint("Longitude:", lng)
        // HERE I NEED to PRINT longitude, latitude, Country Code, City
    }

}
}
```

This closure you put here would run whenever completion block called in `getGPSLocation` function as I rewrite your function above.

Comment: I update code in question according to your advice... but I'm getting errors when I want to debugPrint in **target.swif**.. I commented printing part in **userLocation.swif** t just to check if it's working...

Comment: okay, I edited my closure, now it has 2 variables lat and lng, now you can print these in your block code when calling the function.

Comment: don't forget to call the completion block in getGPSLocation function.

Comment: completion(latitude, longitude) give me error Use of unresolved identifier 'longitude' & 'latitude'... I also try to change in `(_ latitu: String, _ lng: String) -> Void) {` but still same error... :-(

Comment: by completion(latitude, longitude)  i mean you should pass your latitude and longitude variables to the closure to run.

Comment: @MaryamFekri How can we read countryCode from getUserLocation.getGPSLocation {() in } completion? Can you explain it?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with the delegate pattern. With the delegate pattern, you can not only get the longitude, latitude, city and country, but also do error handling.

First, rewrite `fetchCountryAndCity` to include an error handler:

```
func fetchCountryAndCity(location: CLLocation, completion: @escaping (String, String) -> (), errorHandler: @escaping (Error) -> ()) {
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { placemarks, error in
        if let error = error {
            debugPrint(error)
            errorHandler(error)
        } else if let countryCode = placemarks?.first?.isoCountryCode,
            let city = placemarks?.first?.locality {
            completion(countryCode, city)
        }
    }
}
```

Then, create a delegate protocol:

```
protocol GPSLocationDelegate {
    func fetchedLocationDetails(location: CLLocation, countryCode: String, city: String)
    func failedFetchingLocationDetails(error: Error)
}
```

Add a weak property `delegate` to `GPSLocation`:

```
weak var delegate: GPSLocationDelegate?
```

At appropriate times, call the delegate methods:

```
public func getGPSLocation() {

    let locManager = CLLocationManager()
    var currentLocation: CLLocation!
    locManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

    if (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedWhenInUse || CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedAlways) {

        currentLocation = locManager.location

        let latitude = String(format: "%.7f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)
        let longitude = String(format: "%.7f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)
        let location = CLLocation(latitude: currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)

        fetchCountryAndCity(location: location, completion: { countryCode, city in
            delegate?.fetchedLocationDetails(location: location, countryCode: countryCode, city: city)
        }) { delegate?.failedFetchingLocationDetails(error: $0) }

        debugPrint("Latitude:", latitude)
        debugPrint("Longitude:", longitude)
    }
}
```

In the `Post` class, make `Post` conform to `GPSLocationDelegate`:

```
class Post: GPSLocationDelegate {
    func fetchedLocationDetails(location: CLLocation, countryCode: String, city: String) {
         // print the stuff here
     }

     func failedFetchingLocationDetails(error: Error) {
         // handle errors
     }
}
```

Add a property called `gpsLocation`:

```
let gpsLocation = GPSLocation()
```

In the initializer, set its delegate to `self` and call `getLocation`:

```
init() {
    gpsLocation.delegate = self
    gpsLocation.getLocation()
}
```

Your location details should be printed after they have been successfully fetched.

Comment: I also try this but it's only for getting and printing variables in **userLocation.swift**. I need variables to print in another class Post, function Post()  / file **target.swift**